# What is the recommended way to deal with large identity tokens with an MVC client?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 for authentication, but one of the client apps is a simple MVC site with no API access.  I initially set GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint to true so that we could simply use the id token on requests.  Everything works fine, but due to a large number of role claims associated with our users, the id token balloons, the auth cookie gets chunked, and we run into some issues with older browsers.  So, I've set GetClaimsFromUserIndoEndpoint to false and looked for another way to get the claims we need on request.

I've written a custom owin middleware that queries the user info endpoint to add claims at the beginning of the request, with basic caching, but it seems quite a bit sloppier than it should.  The MVC site is set to use hybrid mode, and on the beginning of the request hits the UserInfo endpoint with an access token, caches that info, and appends it to the ClaimsPrincipal.

This achieves my goals but seems like an abuse of access tokens, and I worry it may open us up to future problems since it requires access and refreshes token management.

Is there a better-recommended pattern for keeping id tokens slim, while hydrating them on request before authorization checks take place?

Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: Please take a look at the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/), from the creators of IdentityServer. In fact it uses the same approach of middleware, but has a different source. The idea is to keep tokens as small as possible, use IdentityServer for authentication and client/resource authorization, while user authorization is outsourced to the policy server. The OSS version simply adds the roles, permissions, claims, where the commercial version takes it a step further.

Comment: Ruard van Elburg - I appreciate the suggestion.  That may be useful for certain situations, but in this case we don't want to move authorization rules outside of the primary MVC client app at this point.  We'd really just like to maintain normal OpenIdConnect functionality while simultaneously reducing token size.  But, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Daniel, to be honest, putting user permissions into token is not normal functionality of OIdC. That was invented by MS in their Identity implementation and recent several years they suggest to forget that and use custom policies instead. I can't see any problem in keeping permissions in one app when it's rather small, but you could use API to to fetch them instead of the token. By the way, `UserInfoEndpoint` is an API as well, but it's not specialized for access control.